# I need to bucket sort a string (A-Z) and print it in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to write a code that gets a string untill 100 that includes ONLY A-Z.
and then the code sort the string with bucket sort and print the sorted string.
for example:
Enter a string:  ILOVEAPPLES
The sorted string is: AEEILLOPPSV

i didnt finished the code, i stopped at the print because im stuck.

Im just in my beginning so the code might have alot of problems. sorry for that.

for the full code you can enter:  https://prnt.sc/ndaxyc

```
sort:
    cmp byte[esi], 0
    jz print
    sub byte[esi], "A" ; the cell of esi minus value of A in ascii
    mov al, byte[esi]
    inc byte[esi+al]
    inc esi
    jmp sort
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.  Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly. You should provide all the information inside the question, not as a link.

Comment: **You're using [CountingSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)**, not BucketSort, to sort the characters inside a single string.  You'd use BucketSort to sort multiple strings (e.g. put all the strings that start with `A` into the first bucket, but the later characters are still distinct so the "bucket" can't just be a counter, it has to be a linked list or growable array or similar data structure)

Comment: Addressing modes need all their registers the same size.  Load with `movzx eax, byte[esi]` so you can index an array with `inc byte [counters + eax]`.  (You're trying to `inc` one of the string bytes, so that's obviously wrong.)